# HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL type Servlet Error

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating a Simple Sales System using Jsp Ajax. When I add the data click Add button all Html Table data is successfully pass in to the salesadd Servlet Page I see on the console
I receving data look like this format to Servlet Page

**[{"item":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},
{"item":"Mango","pro_price":"10","qty":"1","total":"10"}]**

But data is not add to the database and show the error like this. I wrote the Full Error below.

**HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
type Status report
messageHTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.**

What I tried so now I attached Below.i think might be the problem with the Product Class

```
Product.java

public class Product 
{ 
    private String item;
    private int price;  
    private int qty;  
    private int total;   
    public String getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(String item)
    {
        this.item = item;
    }
     public int getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
     public int getQty()
    {
        return qty;
    }
    public void setQty(int qty)
    {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

      public int getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total)
    {
        this.total = total;
    }  
}
```

**Servlet Page**

salesadd.java

```
@WebServlet("/salesadd")
public class salesadd extends HttpServlet {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    int row;
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);

     Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst; 
    String jsonData = request.getParameter("data1");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

     Gson gson = new Gson();
    Product data1 = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Product.class);
    String item = data1.getItem();
    int price = data1.getPrice();
    int qty = data1.getQty();
    int total = data1.getTotal();




     try 
    {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/icepos", "root", "");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into sale_product(item,price,qty,total)values(?,?,?,?) ");
        pst.setString(1, data1.getItem());
        pst.setInt(2, data1.getPrice());
        pst.setInt(3, data1.getQty());
        pst.setInt(4, data1.getTotal());
        pst.executeUpdate();

        out.println("<font color='green'>  Record Adddd   </font>");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        out.println("<font color='red'>  Record Failed   </font>");
    }

}







public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse rsp ) throws IOException,ServletException
{
    rsp.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWriter out = rsp.getWriter();


     out.println("<font color='green'>  Record Adddd   </font>");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop the list, like follow:

```
for (Product product : objectList) {
        try
        {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/icepos", "root", "");
            pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into sale_product(item,price,qty,total)values(?,?,?,?) ");
            pst.setString(1, product.getItem());
            pst.setInt(2, product.getPrice());
            pst.setInt(3, product.getQty());
            pst.setInt(4, product.getTotal());
            pst.executeUpdate();

            out.println("<font color='green'>  Record Adddd   </font>");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            out.println("<font color='red'>  Record Failed   </font>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks awesome work sir . really well developer sir u.

Comment: after displayed the Record Adddd msg i need pass in to print.jsp how to call it sir

Comment: you can use the spring boot + mybatis that I advice. It is very simple and quick

Comment: spring boot: [spring](https://spring.io/)  mybatis: https://mybatis.org/. you can follow the guide or search by google

Answer (score 0):

HttpServlet class has another method doGet.
You can override the method, so support the GET request

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path this error also displyed

Comment: sir i did what the way you told me that but no error . record is not addedd

Comment: return "Student [ item: "+item+", pro_price: "+ pro_price+ ",qty: "+qty+", total: "+ total+ " ]";

Comment: you use the follow method to parse json string:public static <T> List<T> getObjectList(String jsonString,Class<T> cls){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonArray arry = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
            for (JsonElement jsonElement : arry) {
                list.add(gson.fromJson(jsonElement, cls));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your client side (from browser) is making a GET request and since you don't have a doGet() method, you are receiving this error.

Although you may add a doGet() method in your class but that will not solve the problem for your use case. You need to send a POST request from your client (check your AJAX code on client side). The GET request is not supposed to have body rather it should have only the requested URL with query parameters.

Further, I see you are trying to map your client sent data

```
[{"item":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},
 {"item":"Mango","pro_price":"10","qty":"1","total":"10"}]
```

to an object of product class using following

```
Product data1 = gson.fromJson(jsonData, Product.class);
```

This will fail as you are are sending an array of products. For a starter just send one JSON object like following

```
{"item":"Chocolate","price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"}
```

Once you make this work, before implementing for your use case, have a read of any GSON tutorial to get a better idea. One tutorial can be found [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

**As a side note**, you should not declare conn, pst etc as class member variables, bring them down in method. Also, close the connection in a final block after try and catch.

Answer (score 0):

you json string is array, but you parse to a object. So you need to parse to a List. Follow:

```
@Test
public void testGson(){
    String jsonStr = "[{\"item\":\"Chocolate\",\"pro_price\":\"32\",\"qty\":\"1\",\"total\":\"32\"}, {\"item\":\"Mango\",\"pro_price\":\"10\",\"qty\":\"1\",\"total\":\"10\"}]";
    List<Product> objectList = getObjectList(jsonStr, Product.class);
    System.out.println(objectList);
}
public static <T> List<T> getObjectList(String jsonString,Class<T> cls){
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray arry = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : arry) {
            list.add(gson.fromJson(jsonElement, cls));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: [Product [ item=Chocolate, pro_price=32, qty=1, total=32], Product [ item=Chocolate, pro_price=32, qty=1, total=32]]    now out display like this sir. i need set String item = objectList.item but i couln't i need to add values in to the database

Comment: you mean you can't insert values to DB?

Comment: yes i cannot  insert values how to insert the values sir String item = objectList.item how to get the item from list